# Is there an article editor similar to Madmimi's email editor?

Tags: editor, markdown

I really like how madmimi works when you want to create an email.
You have blocks that you insert, each block can be text, text+image, image etc
And you fill that block with the content.

Is there an editor that is designed like this?

I need to create a CMS for a website. They need to write articles, and i don't want them to use HTML to edit. Something like Markdown would be great. But there aren't any good editor for general people to use. Markdown can be very confusing for people.

Comment: I would love someone to give a positive answer on this question - the have an AMAZING editor!!! check out their video https://madmimi.com/ and then believe me, you'll want to register (free) and check it out for yourself... I promise you, if you were EVER disappointed by an online WYSIWYG editor before, your wish has been granted!